# Compiler error in using block

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, using-statement

I am trying to catch any errors that crop up when a URL is invalid, below is the original code:

```
public static void mymethod()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();                
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())    
    timer.Stop();
    timeTaken = timer.Elapsed.ToString();
}
```

I have tried to create an exception handler as below, but no luck:

```
public static void mymethod()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    try
    {            
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    }    
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error here...")
    }

    timer.Stop();
    timeTaken = timer.Elapsed.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Jeff Mercado No its the damn browser

Comment: @avatishchev Error 4 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: @James: please ask explicit questions. Yours turns out not to be about exception handling but about a simple syntax error. Always list the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this.

```
public static void ShowResponseAndTimeTaken(string firstline)
{
    try
    {   
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response : {0}", response);
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time taken : {0}", timer.Elapsed); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error : {0}", e.Message);
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `using`-block is incorrect. The correct looks like this:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

or just without the block:

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
response.Dispose()
```

Comment: sorry I don't see what the purpose of this is, can you exaplain

Comment: @James: First of all, using block can't be used in one line, it should have underlying scope. Or just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot intercept it because it is thrown before "try" block:
it is possible that "firstline" variable contains a text with perhaps incorrectly formatted uri,

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also validate URL using regex instead of waiting for exception to be thrown - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx.

Here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) you can find detailed description about GetResponse. Check what exceptions can be thrown and modify your current exception handling.
You shouldn't leave try...catch as it is. At least catch Exception class.

Answer (score 0):

`WebRequest.Create` only throws if the scheme is invalid (the bit before the colon), there is a security error or if the URI you pass is null (although you have not enclosed that statement inside your `try` statement so such errors will be unhandled by the above code anyway).

To handle other errors, you should look at the [`HttpWebResponse.StatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx) property and handle the [HTTP errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in way appropriate to your application.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about syntactic errors, because your code does not compile?

Try to add the missing semicolon on this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("error here...")
```

And the using-block contains no block:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
```

remove the using:

```
var response = request.GetResponse())
```